# PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword in update statement

Tags: sql, plsql

```
UPDATE XXBBBY_WEEK_DATA_CNV_STG 
SET
process_status = CASE 
WHEN error1 = 'No week data Details found' THEN 'E',last_update_time=sysdate
WHEN error1 = 'Processed successfully' THEN 'P'
WHERE  process_status = 'N';
```

Line/Col: 1/1 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line/Col: 6/5 PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword

Answer (score 2):

You need to `END` your `CASE` expressions, and also the current logic seems to be out place here and there:

```sql
UPDATE XXBBBY_WEEK_DATA_CNV_STG 
SET process_status = CASE error1 WHEN 'No week data Details found' THEN 'E'
                                 WHEN 'Processed successfully' THEN 'P' END,
    last_update_time = sysdate
WHERE process_status = 'N';
```

Comment: still i am getting the same error

Comment: Sorry, I had a stray comma inside the `CASE` expression after `'E'`.  Reload your page, it should be working now.